# Checkbox with text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I'm trying to create checkboxes with the text inside the box. Jquery UI appears to already have something similar to what I want - take a look at the "Toggle" button on this page: http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

The example code shown there doesn't seem to work for me though. Here are snippets of the code on my page.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="check"><label for="check">Toggle</label>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#check").button();
    });
</script>
```

Upon inspection, Chrome is telling me that .button() is an undefined function. In turn the checkbox on the page is untouched and remains as a regular checkbox with the text "toggle" on the outside.

Does someone know of another plugin for checkbox functionality and text inside the box? I also want to style the checkbox to be very large and probably change background colour in its checked state. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If `button` is undefined, you're not including jQuery UI properly. Open the console and check for errors.

Comment: I have other jquery elements on the same page which are working fine.

Comment: And they are working fine with jQuery UI methods, like `button` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using an old version of jQuery and jQuery-ui.

In this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/t2jhL9ru/ which uses jQuery 1.7.1 you can see that `button()` is undefined, while in this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/t2jhL9ru/1/ which uses jQuery-1.8.3 and jQuery-Ui-1.9.2, things work fine.

Comment: Thanks! I was using the jquery that came with VS2012.